# What is the use of using process.env.PORT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver, port

When we set the environment variable PORT using something like `set PORT=5000` then we are telling the program directly which port to use. So how is this any different from directly telling it to use port 3000?

Comment: Its just environment variable, so you have one place to put all your configuration

Comment: What do you mean *"directly tell"*? If you mean why do you do e.g. `const port = process.env.PORT` rather than `const port = 3000`, then what about environments where the appropriate port isn't necessarily 3000, and is set via the env var (e.g. Heroku)? External config is one of the [basic principles](https://12factor.net/config) of 12 factor apps, for example.

Comment: Ports (or externalising configuration) aren't specific to Node.

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually I am new to Node and I do not much about how ports work .
Let me try to explain to you where I am getting confused .
When we set cont port =3000 ,there is a possibility that the appropriate port isn't 3000 in some environments ,but when we use const port =process.env.PORT then according to my understanding we have to set then environment variable PORT using set PORT=5000(any port number),so here also we are specifying which port to use.So how is this any different from using cont port =3000.

Comment: Because it's easier to set differently in different environments. If you're changing your source code, rather than just promoting the same codebase to different environments, validation that it still works correctly becomes harder. Someone still has to specify which port to use, so in your dev environment you have to do it (or do e.g. `process.env.PORT || 3000`).

Comment: I know they are not specific to Node . I was trying to tell you that I have come across it first time while studying node .So i have no prior knowledge about it .

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please explain in simpler words and elaborate a bit since I am new to this .

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are used to simplify complexity and padronize values alongside one or many environments, for example, if your service runs on 2 environments, lets say qa and production, with environment variables you can simple write 2 .env files and use diferent values for each one.

Answering your question, yes, if you set an environment variable for a port or set it in an in-code variable, in both ways you're telling the program what port to use.
Well, for your code, doens't matter from where the port are beeing set.

So... Why you would do that using env variables?

Well, that's the main question I think, env variables provide a reliable way to:

- Change values without having to change many places alongside your code;
- Change values betwheen multiple environments;
- Make your app easier to setup and configurate;

Actually they can do more than it. You can check a nice reading about it here: https://medium.com/chingu/an-introduction-to-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them-f602f66d15fa

A suggestion is, use env variables whenever you have to use one of these on your code:

- Execution mode (e.g., production, development, staging, etc.)
- Domain names
- API URL/URI’s
- Ports
- Public and private authentication keys (only secure in server
  applications)
- Group mail addresses, such as those for marketing, support, sales,
  etc. Service account names

But as you can see, it's not mandatory. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Also if you want, check this for further explanation and best-practices:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html